# Plotting multiple equations in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, graph

I want to plot multiple functions according to different values of alpha. My function is: `x^3+x+y+(alpha)*y=0`

```
ezplot('x.^3 + x + y + y', [-10 10 -10 10]);
hold on
ezplot('x.^3 + x + y + 2*y', [-10 10 -10 10]);
hold on
ezplot('x.^3 + x + y + 3*y', [-10 10 -10 10]);
hold on
ezplot('x.^3 + x + y + 4*y', [-10 10 -10 10]);
...
```

When I write the code with for loop which does the same work the code shown above, plot does not show nothing. I do not want to just copy and paste to get 100 functions according to 100 different values of alpha. So in this fashion how can I implement this code with using loops?

[image: Four Function Plotted]

Figure shows the four equation which are shown above.

Comment: use fplot insted of ezplot

Comment: So you didn't show the code you're having problems with, then you say you don't have a problem after all, and there's no question to be seen.  Why don't you try to explain more slowly: what you want, what you tried, what you got, what's wrong with what you got.

Comment: How many values of alpha do you need? You should probably avoid `ezplot` and just use `plot` instead. Of course you'll have to generate `x,y` data.. I'd also suggest restating the equation such that `y = f(x)`, example: `y = @(x,alpha)-(x.^3+x)./(1+alpha);`.

Comment: ezplot() automatically adjusts the plot limits in ways such that the results of the earlier plot might only be partly visible (or out of range completely.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As is stated in the comments MATLAB doesn't recommend the use of `ezplot`. If you're using MATLAB R2017b, then you can use `fimplicit`. If you don't then you can use both `fplot` and `plot` as an alternative. Both, however, need an explicit form. The code for the two latter is then:

for `fplot`:

```
for alpha=1:100
    y = @(x) -(x.^3+x)/(1+alpha);
    fplot(y,[-10 10])
    ylim([-10 10])
    hold on
end
hold off
```

for `plot`:

```
x = -10:.1:10;

for alpha=1:100
    y = -(x.^3+x)/(1+alpha);
    plot(x,y)
    ylim([-10 10])
    hold on
end
hold off
```

I don't have MATLAB R2017b myself, so I couldn't test the code, but if you want to use `fimplicit`, I think it looks like this:

```
for alpha=1:100
    fimplicit(@(x,y) x.^3 +x + (1+alpha)*y, [-10 10 -10 10])
    hold on
end
hold off
```